# Extend Prototype of DOM element

Tags: javascript, oop, prototype, extending

I was wondering if it was possible to extend the prototype of a DOM Element.
I know that

`Element.prototype.newMethod = function(){};`
works, however this applies it to every single element with any tag, so `a`, `form`, `img` will implement the method.

I would like to only add it to a single element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, as said, you can wether extend the prototype of all Elements via:

`Element.prototype.newMethod = function(){};`

However, to add it to a single DOM element, you can do:

`HTMLXyzElement.prototype.newMethod = function(){};`

Where `Xyz` is your element, eg:

`HTMLFormElement`, `HTMLImageElement`, `HTMLAnchorElement`, `HTMLDivElement`.
To find more of these just open a console in your browser and start typing HTML...

Comment: I was trying to turn the following into an extension function `HTMLImageElement.prototype.asyncSrc()`, but it said it didn't see the onload function?  

```function asyncSrc(image, src) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        image.onload = () => resolve();
        image.onerror = reject;
        image.src = src;
    });
}```

Comment: Hey Benjamin, I'm not sure I understand your problem, you should have something like this:

`HTMLImageElement.prototype.asyncSrc = (image, src) => new Promise((y n) => this.onload = () => resolve()))`